# Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm confused about the JQuery UI sortable events handler. How can I make a function fire everytime there is a change e.g. 
    $("#tablename tbody").sortable({
    change: myfunction()
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this way:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
      //code goes here
   }
});
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "sortchange", function(event, ui) {
  //code goes here
});
```

Documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-change

Comment: provide full jquery code ... depdending how you wrote the function

Comment: The bind for some reason wouldn't work, but I've done it the other way now :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"change" event will be fired only if DOM position has changed. You can use [sort](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-sort) event to catch any sorting if that is what you want.